# FOSUserBundle : configuration error (handler)

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I'm using `Symfony 2.1` for a project and trying to use `FOSUserBundle` to manage the users.I am also following the documentation but i'm getting an error:

```
 Unrecognized options "handler" under "fos_user.change_password.form"
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you put something wrong in your config.yml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOSUserBundle recently went through several major changes in `2.0.x`. The [FOSUserBundle documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) as of right now is not up to date and currently is for `1.3.x` and below.

If you would like to still use handlers, you can revert back to `1.3.x` via composer. Take a look at the different releases on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle).

The latest version of FOSUserBundle got rid of handlers and now uses EventListeners. You can take a look at the list of [FOSUserEvents](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php) and decide which event you want to hook on to. You can see an example of subscribing to a FOSUserEvent from the controller on the "Hooking into the controllers" part of the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md).

Also, note that if you're overriding the FOSUserBundle's controller, it now requires the Symfony2 [Request](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) component class as its parameter.

Comment: To revert back to the 1.3.* You should use this solution: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/178